# How to decode the two different struct from different files in a single function golang?

Tags: json, go

I want to decode the two different struct for saving the data into the collection. but it gives error.

The two struct are given below these two files are in the folder named ***models***.

User.go

```
type User struct {
 Id                         int         `json:"id" bson:"_id,omitempty"`
 FirstName                  string      `json:"first_name,omitempty" bson:"first_name,omitempty"`
 LastName                   string      `json:"last_name,omitempty" bson:"last_name,omitempty"`
 EmailId                    string      `json:"email_id,omitempty" bson:"email_id,omitempty"`
 Password                   string      `json:"password,omitempty" bson:"password,omitempty"`
 PhoneNumber                string      `json:"phone_number,omitempty" bson:"phone_number,omitempty"`
 AltPhoneNumber             string      `json:"alt_phone_number" bson:"alt_phone_number"`
 Gender                     string      `json:"gender,omitempty" bson:"gender,omitempty"`
 Note                       string      `json:"note,omitempty" bson:"note,omitempty"`
}
```

Provider.go

```
type Provider struct {
 Id                      int                `json:"id" bson:"_id,omitempty"`
 Uid                     int                `json:"uid" bson:"uid,omitempty"`
 Speed                   string             `json:"speed,omitempty" bson:"speed,omitempty"`
 ProviderCategory        string             `json:"provider_category,omitempty" bson:"provider_category,omitempty"`
 Priority                int                `json:"priority,omitempty" bson:"priority,omitempty"`
}
```

The code I tried to decode them

```
import (
    "encoding/json"
    "go-training/models"
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    "fmt"
)

var provider models.Provider
var user models.User

func SaveProvider(c *gin.Context) {
    response := ResponseController{}
    //decode the struct
    providerErr := json.NewDecoder(c.Request.Body).Decode(&provider)
    fmt.Println(providerErr) //Output:- nil
    userErr := json.NewDecoder(c.Request.Body).Decode(&user)
    fmt.Println(userErr) //output:- EOF
    if userErr != nil {
        fmt.Println("data is not properly formatted")
    }
    if providerErr != nil {
        fmt.Printl?("data is not properly formatted")
    }
}
```

Data entered in the json form-

```
{
 "Id":1,
 "Uid":1,
 "speed":"new",
 "provider_category":"WL",
 "priority":1,
 "first_name":"puneet",
 "last_name":"jindal",
 "email_id":"puneet@gmail.com",
 "password":"poiuytrewq",
 "phone_number":"9876543210",
 "alt_phone_number":"9876543210",
 "gender":"male",
 "note":"phase 7"
}
```

> Error:- EOF

How can I solve this problem? Can anyone help me? Thank you.

Comment: JSON decorder is for JSON streams, so your body has two JSON values concatenated (which is not a valid json document)? Eg sth like { "name": "a" }{ "name": "b" } See https://ahmet.im/blog/golang-json-decoder-pitfalls/ for some info on decoder

Comment: when the page is run on localhost then the data is in the form of json `json.NewDecoder(c.Request.Body).Decode(&provider)` this will arrange the data according to the data entered.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The code in the question does not work because the first decoder reads the entire request body.  The second decoder starts at EOF.

The fix is to slurp up the body to a byte slice and unmarshal twice from that slice:

```
// slurp up the body.  p is a []byte
p, err := ioutil.ReadAll(c.Request.Body)
if err != nil {
   // handler error
}

var provider models.Provider
if err := json.Unmarshal(p, &provider); err != nil {
    // handle error
}

var user models.User
if err := json.Unmarshal(p, &user); err != nil {
     // handle error
}
```